# How to achieve margin between two control group

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, javafx-2

I have the following fxml. After every control group i want to have some space. How to achieve this ?

```
        <Label styleClass="field-view-label" text="%sections.right.section.model-editor.fieldName" />
        <TextField fx:id="fieldName" styleClass="field-view-text" />
        <Label styleClass="field-view-label" text="%sections.right.section.model-editor.fieldType" />
        <ComboBox fx:id="fieldDataType" styleClass="field-view-combobox" />
        <Label styleClass="field-view-label" text="Field Reference" />
        <ComboBox fx:id="fieldReference" styleClass="field-view-combobox" />
        <Label styleClass="field-view-label" text="%sections.right.section.model-editor.reference" />
        <TextField fx:id="fieldValue" styleClass="field-view-text" />
```

CSS

```
.field-header-label{
    -fx-pref-width: 460.0px;
}

.field-view-label {
    -fx-pref-width: 460.0px;
}

.field-view-combobox {
    -fx-pref-width: 460.0px;
}

.field-view-text {
    -fx-pref-width: 460.0px;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap each `Label` and `TextField` in a `VBox`, and add padding to the `VBox`. Something like:

```xml
<VBox styleClass="control">
    <Label styleClass="field-view-label" text="%sections.right.section.model-editor.fieldName" />
    <TextField fx:id="fieldName" styleClass="field-view-text" />
</VBox>
<VBox styleClass="control">
    <Label styleClass="field-view-label" text="%sections.right.section.model-editor.fieldType" />
    <ComboBox fx:id="fieldDataType" styleClass="field-view-combobox" />
</VBox>
<VBox styleClass="control">
    <Label styleClass="field-view-label" text="Field Reference" />
    <ComboBox fx:id="fieldReference" styleClass="field-view-combobox" />
</VBox>
<VBox styleClass="control">
    <Label styleClass="field-view-label" text="%sections.right.section.model-editor.reference" />
    <TextField fx:id="fieldValue" styleClass="field-view-text" />
</VBox>
```

with

```css
.control {
    -fx-padding: 0 0 0 10 ;
}

/* ... */
```